# SQL - Como pegar um dado de uma tabela e inserir outro pré definido?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho um site e preciso criar um código pra enviar emblemas, meu GRAAANDE problema é, o SQL está dando erro
A ideia é inserir na tabela "usuarios_placas" o username e o código do emblema (code_placa). O código tem que pegar todos os usuários da tabela usuário na coluna username e inserir o código do emblema na coluna code_placa.

Resumindo, no site vai ter uma página só com uma caixinha de texto pra por o código e o botao de enviar, o sistema de enviar tá tudo certo, só preciso do comando. Ele tem q pegar TODOS os username da tabela usuarios e adicionar eles JUNTO com o código supondo que seja $emblema na tabela usuarios_placas
O que faz mais sentido pra mim é

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios_placas`(`username`)
SELECT username
FROM usuarios
```

Até ai pra mim acho q tá certo, a questão é onde nesse SQL eu adiciono o valor do $emblema ? (Utilizem $emblema como valor qualquer, conseguir enviar um valor pra ele eu consigo, o problema é inserir, ele não entraria como $emblema, entraria como por exemplo: Emblema Lvl1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é que eu entendi sua dúvida:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios_placas`(`username`, `code_placa`)
SELECT username, 'sua string do emblema'
FROM usuarios
```